# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for validation on transactional object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested

I'm struggling since some hours in order to make validations of nested attributes work in my rails app. A small caveat is that I have to validate nested attributes dynamically based off of their parent's attributes, as the amount of info required changes over time according to where in the process the parent is.

So here's my setup: I have a parent with many different associated models and I want to validate subsequently nested attributes of those every time I save the parent. Given the fact that validations change dynamically, I had to write a custom validation method in the model:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :children_attributes, :status
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
  validate :validate_nested_attributes
  def validate_nested_attributes
    children.each do |child|
      child.descriptions.each do |description|
        errors.add(:base, "Child description value cant be blank") if description.value.blank? && parent.status == 'validate_children'
      end
    end
  end
end


class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :descriptions_attributes, :status
  has_many :descriptions
  belongs_to :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions
end
```

In my controller I call update_attributes on the parent when I want to save. Now the problem is that, apparently, rails runs the validations against the database and not against the object that was modified by the user or the controller. So what might happen is that a child's value is erased by a user and the validations will pass, while later validations will not pass because the item in the database is not valid.

Here's a quick example of this scenario:

```
parent = Parent.create({:status => 'validate_children', :children_attributes => {0 => {:descriptions_attributes => { 0 => {:value => 'Not blank!'}}}})
  #true
parent.update_attributes({:children_attributes => {0 => {:descriptions_attributes => { 0 => {:value => nil}}}})
  #true!! / since child.value.blank? reads the database and returns false
parent.update_attributes({:children_attributes => {0 => {:descriptions_attributes => { 0 => {:value => 'Not blank!'}}}})
  #false, same reason as above
```

The validation works for first-level associations, e.g. if a Child has a 'value' attribute, I could run a validation the way I do. The problem is with deep associations that apparently cannot be validated before saving.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to solve this? The only way I currently see is by saving records, validating them afterwards and deleting / reverting them if the validation fails, but I am honestly hoping for something more clean.

Thank you all in advance!

**SOLUTION**

So it turns out I was running validations on deep nested models by referencing those directly in the custom validation, this way:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  has_many :descriptions, :through => :children
  [...]
  def validate_nested_attributes
    descriptions.each do |description|
      [...]
    end
  end
end
```

Which for some reason leads to the problems I was having above. Thanks Santosh for testing my example code and reporting it was working, this pointed me in the right direction to figure this out.

For future reference, the code in the original question works for this sort of dynamic, deeply-nested validations.

Comment: There are few errors in your code. It could be typo. 1. 'Child value can't be blank' -- single quote inside single quote. 2. && parent.status = 'validate_children' -- This is not comparison. its assignment

Comment: sorry about the typos! The code here is just a simplified example of my app so that's not the reason it is not working, but thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) for this

with the following validation in Child

```
validates :value, :presence => true, :if => "self.parent.status == 'validate_children'"
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh, thanks for the very quick answer! I already stepped into validates_associated but the general feeling around here is that it is more of an hassle than anything. Is there a way of validating associated records attributes only from the parent's model without touching their own model? This would be needed because, in my setup, the child can live in the database without a value but only if the parent's status is different from 'validate_children'.

Comment: In that case, you can add validation in children like this: validates :value, :presence => true, :if => "self.parent.status == 'validate_children'"

Comment: Hey Santhosh, thanks again for the reply. The problem is that my app is a bit more complicated than the example and it involves polymorphic associations as well, therefore it would be much better to keep validations at the parent level. I just figured out the validations work on first-level nested models but they don't on deep nested ones. E.g. if children have descriptions, the validation will work for children but not for their descriptions.

Comment: I tried your code with Post-Comment models and it works for me. ( I had changed errors.add[:base, msg]  to  errors.add(:base, msg) )

Comment: Thanks for your help Santhosh, I still didn't manage to get it working on my side and unfortunately the code is way more complicated than the example, which makes it difficult to just copy-paste it here. For the moment, I kept the first-level validations within the model and moved deep nested ones to the controller, where I have to first save the record if the first validations pass and then check for the deeper ones. I will try a simpler version and see if it works as it does for you.